# SaltStack - Use salt:// to define working directory in cmd.run state

Tags: salt-stack

I'm quite new to SaltStack and I'm wondering if there's a way to use `salt://` URI where it's not supported natively.

In this case I would execute a command in a specific directory and I would like to specify the directory using `salt://` like the following:

```
test_cmd:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo a > test
    - cwd: salt://my-state/files/
```

which actually doesn't work giving the error

`Desired working directory "salt://my-state/files/" is not available`

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: what's the absolute path of `salt://my-state/files/`.  i'm afraid i can't understand the real question.

Comment: @sel-fish the thing is that actually `salt://` represents the path where SaltStack states are installed, so it acts just like a variable. Of course I could also hard-code the path (e.g. /srv/salt/...) but then it wouldn't be dynamic if it changes in future..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do it the way you want, but you might be able to get what you need by combining file.recurse with cmd.run or cmd.wait:

```
test_cmd:
  file.recurse:
    - name: /tmp/testcmd
    - source: salt://mystate/files
  cmd.wait:
    - name: echo a > test
    - cwd: /tmp/testcmd
    - watch:
      - file: test_cmd
```

That copies the salt folder to the minion, then uses the copy as the working directory.